# mule json payload to db values returns null from REST

Tags: mule

My mule flow:

```
 <flow name="classmappingFlow1" doc:name="classmappingFlow1">
        <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="${hostname}" port="${port}" path="insertClass" connector-ref="ConnectorWithoutMuleSession" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <jersey:resources doc:name="REST">
            <component class="com.mycompany.mulesoft.rest.AccountMappingService"/>
        </jersey:resources>
        <json:json-to-object-transformer doc:name="JSON to Object"/>
        <logger message="Payload======#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <logger message="=====Company===#[payload.Company]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <db:insert config-ref="Oracle_Configuration" doc:name="Database">
            <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[insert into SIAS_CONFIGURATION values(1, 1,1234,#[payload.Company],'Y','N','Y','you',sysdate,'you',sysdate)]]></db:parameterized-query>
        </db:insert>
    </flow>
```

Console:

```
Payload======[{"Company":"KLM","Class":"Y","Location":"N","Department":"Y","EmplId":"1234"}]
=====Company===null
```

JSON Data:

```
[
 {
 "Company":"KLM",
 "Class":"Y",
 "Location":"N",
 "Department":"Y",
 "EmplId":"1234"
 }
]
```

Rest Component:

```
@POST
@Path("/setClass")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String classSettings(@Payload String content){
    return content;
}
```

Issue: I am getting null values and no data(empty) inserted to db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `returnClass="java.util.List"` in `json:json-to-object-transformer` after **jersey:resources** like the following :-

```
<json:json-to-object-transformer returnClass="java.util.List" doc:name="JSON to Object"/>
```

Comment: I tried this, didnot work. Data is already present in payload, i.e it shows in the first logger: Payload======

Comment: If you don't use **returnClass="java.util.List"** in **json:json-to-object-transformer** .. you will not able to get value in **#[payload.Company]** ... Data is showing in first logger because in the log you are using **#[message.payload]** and thus the entire payload is shown ... but since you have not used return class **java.util.List** , you will not get any value in second log in **#[payload.Company]**  and it will show null always

Comment: Yes correct, but my input was a array of json data, modified #[payload[0].Company] to get the data from array. that was the reason earlier data was not printing.